# Notes in reading money in Chinese (using 两 and 零）

Tags: number

How should one read "3.24元"?
a)三块二毛四
b)三块两毛四

also, "15.08元":
a)十五块八分
b)十五块零八分

also, "4.52元"
a) 四块五毛二分
b) 四块五毛两分

Answer (score 3, accepted):

三块两毛四

十五块零八分

四块五毛两分  or 四块五毛二

二元、二毛、二分 are all unnatural. Use 两 when 块 毛 or 分 is followed, use 二 if not.

零 is used when there’s 0 毛 but nonzero 分 and 块.

Answer (score 1):

元 角 分 are standard Mandarin, while 块 毛 分 are colloquial usage. If it is an exam or some formal occasion you need to use the corresponding, but it is perfectly understandable to mix it up on a daily basis.